# Which UI toolkit are you using with your Ember.js apps?

Tags: ember.js

I just started using Ember.js recently and I love the functionality. I'm wondering which UI toolkit you might be using to tie into design side of your applications.

Answer (score 4):

Personaly, I am using [Twitter's bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) library, which is quite low level, but pretty clean.

Comment: +1 On using Bootstrap. However you'll need a framework that will integrate with it's components to unlock it's full potential in serious Ember apps. There are some okay OSS frameworks out there that do this (search github) but honestly you'll be better off writing your own... Until May 1st that is. More on that later ;)

Comment: Now don't leave me hanging Roy. Fess up!

Answer (score 4):

For Bootstrap integration with Ember, take a look at this project I started two days ago:

https://github.com/ember-addons/bootstrap-for-ember

It really fun and easy to use and lightly integrate bootstrap and ember components altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter Bootstrap is my preffered choice when it comes to UI especially when prototyping something quickly, recently i have started to use EmberJS and have looked into this as well. So far i have found https://github.com/emberjs-addons/ember-bootstrap

I will update this as my search continues.

Hope this helps with your project!

Comment: This one is a little outdated, the developer does not recommend using it anymore. https://github.com/ember-addons/bootstrap-for-ember is a good alternative.

Comment: Thanks Paul, top answer currently has this, so i will leave this as is for now, as another option if someone ever picks ember-bootstrap up again etc.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter bootstrap is a great UI frameworks no doubts but I feel it is too mainstream these days. Hence my personal preference is [Metro UI CSS](http://metroui.org.ua/), it's sleek and great for developing mobile applications using HTML5

Comment: These guys should really switch their code snippets to monospace fonts.

Comment: You really have to like the Microsoft metro look to use this framework.

Comment: @V3ss0n I know! I kinda liked it back then when it was new, perhaps due to the fact that it looked cooler compared to bootstrap v2.3. The current bootstrap is pretty cool though, I use it regularly in all my projects by configuring the less variables as per my need.

Answer (score 0):

I am just starting with emberjs also. Actually I use JQMobile. But I have some issues with it. As I want have a Mobile look and feel, I will try more.

But even if have not use bootstrap with EmberJs I think it will be easier to use as it's only css.

With a UI toolkit that use JavaScript and is owns attributs(exemple : data-role="List"... with JQuery Mobile) you can have rendering issues. I think this is because that Metamorphose/Handlebars and JQuery Mobile both modify the DOM on the fly and it can be tricky to get all work right.

But I am not a EmberJs or JQ Mobile Guru :-)

Sorry for my english, it isn't my mother tongue.

Just one Question .. what is a OSS framework and do you have the links on GitUb

Comment: Tolbard, OSS stands for open source software.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe old but I've used this addon on over 5 projects so far with great success. The project is well maintained and flexible. The maintainer is active and takes pull requests efficiently.

http://kaliber5.github.io/ember-bootstrap/

Disclaimer: I am not officiated with this project beyond that of an end consumer.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at Ember Paper if you like Google Material:
http://miguelcobain.github.io/ember-paper/